# accessing hugging face data set actual file name

Tags: python, json, dataset, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I am new to hugging face and have recently upload an audio dataset in my private repository. I am accessing it using access token and it downloads the data just fine. However, the original audio file names are like "abc.wav" but the downloaded version has name in hexadecimal like fff29eed0b3102ee448be3cc68c019d1232930c947dd3b3defc9156c5356afc2 for each audio file. so the cached folder right now has 3 types of files for each audio file. Like

1. fff29eed0b3102ee448be3cc68c019d1232930c947dd3b3defc9156c5356afc2
2. fff29eed0b3102ee448be3cc68c019d1232930c947dd3b3defc9156c5356afc2.json
3. fff29eed0b3102ee448be3cc68c019d1232930c947dd3b3defc9156c5356afc2.lock

The original audio file name is in .json file of each audio file like "$16362619add875/dataset/abc.wav", "etag": null}
"
I also iterated through the data set dict but it only has the audio data as array and the sampling frequency and not the actual file name.

My all computations ahead need to address the file by its original name for some reason. What would be an easy way to do it? or is there any way to configure something on hugging face that can perhaps add the file name to the dataset dict?